# Syntax error in python list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

```
`print [ [i, j, k] for i in range(x + 1) for j in range(y + 1) for k in range(z + 1) if ((i + j + k) != n)]`
```

`File "solution.py", line 7
    print [ [i, j, k] for i in range(x + 1) for j in range(y + 1) for k in range(z + 1) if ((i + j + k) != n)]`
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Not able to understand what is wrong with my code.

Comment: That is not proper syntax, as the error says. `print()` is enclosed by `()`, not `[]`

Comment: Sorry my mind got freezed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print should be enclosed by ().